# Adding an Image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been using Dreamweaver for a while and have not needed to add an image manually in css for a while. I needed to edit something on a computer which doesn't have Dreamweaver and I can't see what the issue is. All my css is linked correctly with my html document. My image is in a folder on my desktop called "images". The image is called "golf.jpg" The code is

```
header .fullheight {
background-image: url(images/golf.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

I feel like I am missing something right in front of me, but can't see the issue. All help appreciated!

Comment: There could be a million issues here, but without a [mcve] we're just taking guesses in the dark.

Comment: I had an image that was linked to the desktop but had to change it, so I know the only issue is the image. Am I messing something up regarding linking the image?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I think I realized the issue but still need some help. I got confused since I am operating on a different computer with a different arrangement of files. My images folder is in this order: Downloads-->responsive-->development-->images. Can you tell me how to link it correctly?

Comment: try adding a width and height to the class.

Comment: I didn't add quotes to the path, that caused the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you need to add quotes:

```
background-image: url('images/golf.jpg);
```

Or you should figure out what is the root dir to understand whether path is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You write: "My image is in a folder on my desktop called "images"."

So this will only work if the CSS file itself is on the desktop, too. (which I wouldn't recommend - create at least a folder for all the files of your website project)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should store your images in:
computer > xampp > htdocs > images
(if you're using xampp)

### Also, you should include quotes for your attribute

```
     `background-image: url("images/golf.jpg");
```